# Does Free theams of wordpress with incripted code is hacking my sites?

Tags: wordpress, security, wordpress-theming

Do any free Wordpress themes contain encrypted code that can hack my site? If it is possible, can you please tell us how to find and remove that code?

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you download via the Wordpress Dashboard - be it themes or plugins - are scoured by the Wordpress team before being made publicly available.

What you have to watch out for, as you would with any third-party, are Free Themes that are available outside of Wordpress, but unavailable within the Wordpress community. Some things to remember:

- When downloading a Plugin, make sure you're either downloading it from the Wordpress Plugin Repository, or that it's at least available from within their repository. Plugins that are unavailable through this service should be treated with a healthy dose of skepticism. If you download a plugin and it isn't available through Wordpress' own service, check the site from which the plugin was downloaded. Is it reputable? Google search the site and plugin. If nothing comes up, check to make sure that all code contained within is at least readable and self-documenting. If it isn't, remove it.
- When downloading a free theme, the above applies. Check to make sure that the theme is also available through Wordpress' Theme repository. If it isn't, check the source website's reputation. If that isn't available, check the source code. If it's not understandable in the least, remove it.

Your best bet is to make sure that everything you download and install comes from either the Wordpress Dashboard, or a trusted Premium website. Trusted sources are key. If you don't trust the source, don't download the content.